# Can poly2tri create new points in the polygon?

Tags: polygon, triangulation

Is that possible that [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) creates new points for the triangulation, or does it always use the given points only (the points on the contour and holes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Contrained Delaunay Triangulation in 2D, the only points in your model will be those of the input polygons.
Adding points inside the domain will need a mesher like the one of [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html). Python and Java bindings are also [available](https://github.com/cgal/cgal-swig-bindings).

Answer (score 0):

You can give interior points to poly2tri but it does not create any new points.